# Weak l.s.c. of $L^2$-norm on $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-topology

In the image below, the space $X$ is $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$, and $\Omega$ is a bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^N$ so that the Sobolev imbeddings hold.
It is from the article of G. Auchmuty - Dual Variational Principles for Eigenvalue Problems.

[image]

I don't quite understand the part in red. In particular, why do we need the imbedding to be compact?

I would argue that you don't really need that, since the $L^2$-norm, being a norm, is a convex function, and it is clearly strongly continuous on $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega)$, hence it should also be weakly l.s.c., without any need for compactness.

**Edit:** as requested, the functional $f_1$ and $f$ are defined as follows[image]

where $\mu$ is any positive real number.

Comment: What are $f_1$ and $f$?

Comment: @CheeHan I edited the question including the definitions of f and f_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard consequence of Rellich's compactness theorem; weak $W^{1,2}$ convergence implies strong $L^2$ convergence. Note the convexity argument is insufficient here, as you want weak continuity and not weak lower semicontinuity.

To see this, suppose $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,2}_0(\Omega),$ so in particular we have $\{u_n\}$ is uniformly bounded in $W^{1,2},$ that is
$$ \sup_{n} \lVert u \rVert_{W^{1,2}(\Omega)} < \infty. $$
Hence by the compact embedding, there is a strongly convergence subsequence $u_{n_k} \to v$ in $L^2(\Omega).$ In particular $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ *and* $u_n \rightharpoonup v$ weakly in $L^2(\Omega),$ so by uniqueness $u=v.$ This shows that every subsequence of $\{u_n\}$ admits a strongly $L^2$-convergence subsequence to $u$ in $L^2(\Omega),$ so strong $L^2$-convergence follows.

Strictly speaking I have only argued sequential continuity, but I assume this will suffice for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks! I guess my mistake was considering that weakl l.s.c. was sufficient, but as one can see from the definition of the functional f there is a minus sign before the L^2-norm, hence we indeed need the weak continuity, thus the compact embedding.

Comment: another comment: sequential continuity is sufficient to prove that f is weakly l.s.c.,  because sublevel sets for f are W^{1,2}-norm bounded because f is coercive, hence to prove that said sublevel sets are weakly closed we can reason with sequences because we know that in separable hilbert spaces bounded subsets are weakly metrizable. Would you agree?

Comment: @vampip I agree, that sounds like it'll work.